# JavaFX - why do I get "Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream" when trying to open an unpacked .xlsx file with Apache POI?

Tags: java, javafx, apache-poi

I have a `raw` folder in one of my packages under the `src` directory which contains .xlsx files. When I launch my program I initialize the `Lists` folder in the root directory and unpack my .xlsx files there using the following code:

```
public static void unpack(String type, boolean replace){
    File f;
    ArrayList<String> list = null;
    switch (type){
        case "N5":
            if(Main.curLocale.getLanguage().equals("ru")||Main.curLocale.getLanguage().equals("uk")||Main.curLocale.getLanguage().equals("be")) {
                String l[] = {"n5_home_body_rus.xlsx", "n5_travelling_studying_formulas_rus.xlsx", "n5_time_numbers_rus.xlsx", "n5_adjectives_rus.xlsx", "n5_verbs_rus.xlsx", "n5_borrowings_rus.xlsx", "n5_pron_adv_interj_prep_cnt_rus.xlsx"};
                list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(l));
            }else {
                String l[] = {"n5_home_body_eng.xlsx", "n5_travelling_studying_formulas_eng.xlsx", "n5_time_numbers_eng.xlsx", "n5_adjectives_eng.xlsx", "n5_verbs_eng.xlsx", "n5_borrowings_eng.xlsx", "n5_pron_adv_interj_prep_cnt_eng.xlsx"};
                list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(l));
            }
            break;
        case "N4":
            if(Main.curLocale.getLanguage().equals("ru")||Main.curLocale.getLanguage().equals("uk")||Main.curLocale.getLanguage().equals("be")) {
                String l[] = {"n4_nouns_1_rus.xlsx", "n4_nouns_2_rus.xlsx", "n4_verbs_rus.xlsx", "n4_adjectives_adverbs_misc_rus.xlsx", "n4_borrowings_rus.xlsx"};
                list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(l));
            }else {
                String l[] = {"n4_nouns_1_eng.xlsx", "n4_nouns_2_eng.xlsx", "n4_verbs_eng.xlsx", "n4_adjectives_adverbs_misc_eng.xlsx", "n4_borrowings_eng.xlsx"};
                list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(l));
            }
            break;
    }
    Optional<ButtonType> result;
    Alert a = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    ButtonType yes = new ButtonType(Main.curBundle.getString("yes"));
    ButtonType no = new ButtonType(Main.curBundle.getString("no"));
    a.getButtonTypes().remove(0,2);
    a.getButtonTypes().addAll(yes,no);
    for(String lst : list) {
        result = null;
        f = new File("Lists/" + lst);
        if (f.exists() && !replace) {
            a.setHeaderText(lst + Main.curBundle.getString("already_exists"));
            result = a.showAndWait();
        }
        if (!f.exists() || (result != null && result.get() == yes)) {
            try {
                InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("raw/"+lst);
                byte buffer[] = new byte[is.available()];
                is.read(buffer);
                is.close();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Lists/"+lst);
                fos.write(buffer);
                fos.close();
                if(Main.dbc!=null){
                    if(!Main.listsFiles.containsKey(lst)) {
                        mDbxFile dbf = mDbxFile.upload(Main.dbc, "Lists\\" + lst, "/Lists/" + lst, "/Lists");
                        if (dbf != null) {
                            Main.listsFiles.put(lst, dbf);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exc) {
            }
        }
        if(Main.dbc!=null) {
            Main.saveOldDbxFiles(Main.listsFiles, new File(Main.LMETADATA));
        }
    }
}
```

Then I read the files using Apache POI in the following way:

```
File f = new File(Settings.CurList);
InputStream fis = null;
if(f.exists()&&f.isFile()) {
     fis = new FileInputStream(f);
}else{
     return;
}
XSSFWorkBook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

This approach works when I launch from the IDE (I use Intellij Idea). Unfortunately, if I unpack the .xlsx files from a deployed application, the line `XSSFWorkBook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);` generates the following exception:

```
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:194)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$ThresholdInputStream.read(ZipSecureFile.java:168)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource$FakeZipEntry.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:130)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:57)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:91)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:273)
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:273)
at JlexMain.Main.getTableValues(Main.java:1390)
at JlexMain.Main.createTable(Main.java:1541)
at JlexMain.Main.showEditorScene(Main.java:713)
at JlexMain.Main$5$1.run(Main.java:315)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$50/32681650.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/14102484.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/8539234.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I checked the files opening them in Excel. 4 of 7 are really corrupt: "n5_home_body_rus.xlsx", "n5_travelling_studying_formulas_rus.xlsx", "n5_time_numbers_rus.xlsx", "n5_adjectives_rus.xlsx". And there is a pattern: they are first 4 files in the array.

So, how can I bypass this strange behavior?

Comment: Why on earth are you using an `InputStream` when you have a `File`? The [Apache POI docs are very very clear on that being slower and needing more memory](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)!

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I replaced InputStream with File. However, this doesn't solve anything. I rechecked the files from the folder. It turned out that some part of them are really corrupt: namely first 4 files from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `BufferedInputStream` solved my problem:

```
InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("raw/"+lst);
BufferedInputStream bs = new BufferedInputStream(is);
byte buffer[] = new byte[is.available()];
bs.read(buffer);
is.close();
bs.close();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Lists/"+lst);
fos.write(buffer);
fos.close();
```

I still do not understand what was wrong with using a simple `InputStream` though.

Comment: don't use available.  it's a terrible method.  the correct way to copy a stream is using a loop, reading until you get no more data.  also, you need to pay attention to the return value from the read() method.

Comment: I had a similar problem but with writing a gziped byte array and using a BufferedWriter resolved the issue.